# fail to get extra info. from login response in gin-jwt

Tags: go, jwt

i tried to apply the gin-jwt to backend(gin) of my react app, wanna get the user id and role info. for RBAC. i can login and get the token accordingly, but when i tried to get role info from LoginResponse function, the userid and role field is blank.

i want to know the flow of login, why it doesnt work ?

PayloadFunc:

```
authMiddleware, err := jwt.New(&jwt.GinJWTMiddleware{
    Realm:       "test zone",
    Key:         []byte("mysecretkey"),
    Timeout:     time.Hour,
    MaxRefresh:  time.Hour,
    IdentityKey: identityKey,

    PayloadFunc: func(data interface{}) jwt.MapClaims {
        if v, ok := data.(*User); ok {
            return jwt.MapClaims{
                identityKey: v.UserName,
                role: v.Role,
                email: v.Email,
            }
        }
        return jwt.MapClaims{}
    },
```

Authenticator:

```
Authenticator: func(c *gin.Context) (interface{}, error) {
        var loginVals Login
        if err := c.BindJSON(&loginVals); err != nil {
            return "", jwt.ErrMissingLoginValues
        }
        plainpass := loginVals.Password
        session, err := mgo.Dial(SERVER)
        ce(err)
        colQuerier := bson.M{"username": loginVals.Username}
        err = session.DB(DATABASE).C("asys_users").Find(colQuerier).One(&loginVals)
        ce(err)
        defer session.Close()
        if CheckPasswordHash(plainpass, loginVals.Password) {
            return &User{
                UserName:  loginVals.Username,
                Role:  loginVals.Role,
                Email: loginVals.Email,
            }, nil
        }

        return nil, jwt.ErrFailedAuthentication
    },
```

LoginResponse:

```
LoginResponse: func(c *gin.Context, code int, token string, expire time.Time) {
        claims := jwt.ExtractClaims(c)
        fmt.Println(claims) . // only map[], nothing
        c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
            "code":   http.StatusOK,
            "token":  token,
            "expire": expire.Format(time.RFC3339),
            "userid": claims["id"], // this field is null
            "role": claims["role"],  // this field is null  
            "email": claims["email"],  // this field is null
        })
    },
```

Comment: `if v, ok := data.(*User); ok` - have you verified that data is of type *User? If it's not, you are returning an empty claims struct.

Comment: @Gavin yes, i verified the data and confirmed it has data

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get extractClaims from login endpoint 'cause there is no token on Authorization header. The cheat way is set a new variable to context from Authenticator func.